# unable to render nested props from Github's GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-api, graphql, relayjs

I am attempting to fetch some of [Github's GraphQL data](https://developer.github.com/early-access/graphql/object/query/) and display it using React & Relay. The two problems I have are that it appears relay is adding aliases to the response (making it difficult to reference), and not all the item's queried are getting passed into my component `props`. In the code below I can render `this.props.relay.variables.name` but get undefined when trying to loop over `this.props.relay.variables.issues`

```js
// AppQuery.js
import Relay from 'react-relay'
export default {
  relay : Component => Relay.QL `
    query {
      relay {
        ${Component.getFragment('relay')}
      }
    }
  `
};
```

```js
// AppContainer.js
import Relay from 'react-relay'
import App from './AppComponent'

export default Relay.createContainer(App, {
  initialVariables: {
    owner: "rails",
    name: "rails",
    count: 10
  },
  fragments: {
    relay: () => Relay.QL `
      fragment on Query {
        repository(owner: $owner, name: $name) {
          name
          owner
          description
          issues(first: 20) {
            edges {
              node {
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }`
  }
});
```

```js
//AppComponent.js
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.relay.variables.name}</h1>
        <ul>
          { this.props.relay.variables.issues.edges.map((issue) => {
            return(<li>{issue.node.title}</li>)
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the response preview it appears that I am successfully fetching the specified data.

[image: github graphQL response object]

But when I console log `this.props` some properties from the fetch are missing.

[image: result after console logging this.props]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing the `variables` of the fragment you have to access the query response by using `this.props.relay.repository` in yout `App` component.

For example, to map over all issues:

```
<ul>
  { this.props.relay.repository.issues.edges.map((issue) => {
    return(<li>{issue.node.title}</li>)
  })}
</ul>
```

Comment: that makes sense but I am still getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'issues' of undefined`. Could it have anything to do with my response getting aliased? `{"data":{"relay":{"_repository41jr1f":` I'm not sure why this is happening to certain properties.

Comment: do you try to access the data on the Relay container, or in the inner component? based on your output, it seems like you try to access it in the Relay container where it does not belong. The Relay container passes the data to the inner component as props, once the query has finished.